# Python if statement not working with two conditions

Tags: python, list, set, google-colaboratory

I was trying to write a code in python but getting error.

```
use_letter=[]
word = "admit"
guess = 'b'
if guess in word and not in use_letter:
  use_letter.append(guess)
```

Here I create a list `use_letter`. I wanted to append `guess` if the letter already in word but not in use_letter. However, I got error `if guess in word and not in use_letter:` in this line.

Error message: **invalid syntax**

I also want to make the use_letter list, a unique element list, where no duplicate elements will be allowed.

How do I create a unique list?

Comment: try `if guess in word and guess not in use_letter:`

Comment: `and` combines two *values*, not two partial expressions. `guess in word` is a complete expression that has a value; `not in use_letter` is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add guess each time you create a new condition. Try this:

```py
if guess in word and guess not in use_letter:
  use_letter.append(guess)
  use_letter = list(dict.fromkeys(use_letter)))
```

The last line removes any duplicates.

Comment: Yes it works. Can you please help me in my 2nd question. How can I make a list an unique list?